# What public transport options exist between Calgary, Banff, and Jasper?

Tags: public-transport, canada, alberta, calgary, banff

I and some friends hope to town hop in Alberta in a couple of weeks, and are wondering about our options.

We are considering renting a car, but are also aware Greyhound services these towns.  Are there any other options for getting between them - a shuttle perhaps, that we might be able to utilise?

Comment: I would definitely go for renting a car. You probably want to see more of the area than the towns alone. The Icefield Parkfield alone will take you a day, even tough plain driving time is 3-4 hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend a car. Once you get 2 or 3 people, it's by far the cheapest way to go. Also, it lets you keep your options open for when and where you want to go.

If you're budget conscious, check out [Rent-a-Wreck](http://www.rentawreck.ca/rent.asp). I did a trip with my girlfriend a few years back from Calgary to Kelowna and we went with them. Was a good experience. The cars aren't 'wrecks', they're just not as nice as the average rental agency. You also don't have to be 25 to get a normal rate, and the prices are very good.

Comment: Despite asking for public transport, having ended up taking a car, I can confirm, it should NOT be done by public transport - there's so much you want to see and get to that you really do want a car for it.

Answer (score 4):

There are apparently buses and trains.  Though trains seem to operate only part of the way.  Basically from Jasper to Edmonton.  When it comes to Calgary I can only find buses (even on [Via Rail](http://www.viarail.ca))

From Jasper to Banff the same [Rail Canada](http://www.viarail.ca) refers you to [Red Arrow Bus Lines](https://reservia.viarail.ca/search/carrier.aspx?id=RedArrow&type=arr), which for whatever reasons doesn't allow you to book Jasper->Banff trip online.

Of course there is always [Greyhound Canada](https://www.greyhound.ca), which offers service to Jasper on Greyhound Express via Edmonton from Calgary or direct to Banff.

Comment: Thanks, but definitely no trains - ViaRail stopped running trains through to Calgary a few years back :(  The line now runs from Vancouver through Jasper to Edmonton - which isn't between Jasper, Banff and Calgary - and onwards.  And I was asking about options *other* than Greyhound ;)